# vertically and horizontally aligning two inline divs inside another div... and collapsing them nicely

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment, alignment

Okay so this question is asked all over teh interwebs, including on this site multiple times. But I can't seem to apply the answers to others' problems to my own. So here's my specific case:

```
<div class="logo-align_container">
    <div class="logo_image">
        <img src="images/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo_text">
        <div class="site_name">
            <h1>foo</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="site_slogan">
            <h2>bar</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br class="clearBoth" />
</div>
```

How do I centre `logo_image` and `logo_text` vertically and horizontally within `logo-align_container`? Whenever I apply the fixes scattered across the web I manage to horizontally center the divs, but `logo_text` will always be aligned at the top of `logo-align_container`, and nothing I can do repositions it.

Moreover, the image and text make up a considerable part of the page. When the window is too small for them to be positioned inline **(which they currently are, through `float: left` on both and `.clearBoth { clear: both; }`**, I'd like to have them collapse so that `logo_text` falls below `logo_image` (which is already happening so far) but also so that both are still horizontally and vertically aligned. If this doesn't come as part of the fix to the first problem, it'd be really great if it could be accomplished separately.

If I had to give `logo-align_container` a fixed height, it would be 532px.

Thank you for your time!

EDIT: wheresrhys' solution almost hits the mark. Here's what it's not accomplishing which I would like it to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXWRe.png

Comment: Are the images of the same height?

Comment: Could you post a code of your attempt and possible on jsfiddle as well?

Comment: yunzen: There is only one image. Truth: my attempt looked basically like wheresrhys' below.

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle demonstrates a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/wheresrhys/t6pUq/ using `display:inline-block`

A few points

1. It won't work in ie7 and below as inline-block isn't supported on elements which have `display:inline` by default. A decent fallback in that scenario would be to use display block and then set `margin: x auto 0` on logo_wrapper, where x is a value that puts the logo and title roughly in the vertical center.
2. I modified the html slightly - adding a wrapper around all the elements needing to be centered is necessary, and also the comments prevent the whitespace affecting the positioning of the `inline-block` element.

Comment: Your solution is good except when `.logo_wrapper` is large enough to accommodate `logo_image` and `logo_text` inline. When that happens, I want the two placed side by side and vertically aligned. From this position, when the window is shrunk to the point where the two can no longer fit inline `logo_text` should fall under `logo_image`, which your solution does, but the whole thing still needs to be centre-aligned. With your solution the whole thing is left-aligned to a significant degree. I'll get an image comparison up ASAP to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Achieving the text alignment for teh side by side case shodul be possible by applying a similar technique again to the items within logo_wrapper, but achieveing teh effect where the text center aligns beneath the image when there's no room will probably need media-queries (assuming this layout is needed on smaller resolution screens/windows)